# Specific page route in ReactJS via JSON Id

Tags: json, reactjs

I want to route to a specific page and show a specific JSON Object. If JSON Object contains `ID: 1` then it should go to `localhost:300/users/1` and show the data of Id 1. I have also mapped another JSON which contains addresses of users and this is I have done so far.

`User.jsx`

```
import React from "react";
import users from "../data/PersonData.json";
import adresses from "../data/StreetAddress.json";

class Users extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Users: []
    };
  }
  render() {
    const result = {
      Users: users.User.map(user => ({
        ...user,
        adresses: adresses.StreetAddress.filter(
          adr => adr.PersonId === user.Id
        ).map(({ PersonId, ...rest }) => rest)
      }))
    };
    return <div id="users"> {JSON.stringify(result)} </div>;
  }
}

export default Users;
```

and it results into whole JSON Object mapped with address, How can I route it to specific ID i.e. `Id` which is in

`PersonData.json`

```
{
  "User": [
    {
      "BossId": 3,
      "DateOfBirth": "1966-09-27T00:00:00",
      "FamilyName": "Montejano",
      "Gender": "Unspecified",
      "GivenName": "Trinh",
      "Id": 8,
      "Title": "Tech Manager"
    },
  ]
}
```

So when a user is routed to `localhost:3000/users/8` it should show only specific data of user 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in the following way, I took the URL Parameters and got the ID from there and matched it with JSON Object which is looping.

In `App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Users from "./Components/Users";
import User from "./Components/User";
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/users" name="users" component={Users} />
              <Route path="/user/:id" name="user" component={User} />
            </Switch>
          </>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and in `User.jsx`

```
import React from "react";
import users from "../data/PersonData.json";
import adresses from "../data/StreetAddress.json";

class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Users: []
    };
  }
  render() {
    const result = {
      Users: users.User.map(user => ({
        ...user,
        adresses: adresses.StreetAddress.filter(
          adr => adr.PersonId === user.Id
        ).map(({ PersonId, ...rest }) => rest)
      }))
    };
    const params = this.props.match.params.id;
    return JSON.stringify(result.Users[params]);
  }
}

export default User;
```

I have reused the same code in the question.

Comment: The issue with this is I'm not getting desired output right now